# How to choose what is effected by transition manager in android?

Tags: android, kotlin, animation, layout

I'm finding the convenience of `TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition()` negated by how counterintuitive it is.  I just want to animate some changes to the layout but not others and it seems like just moving layout adjustment you don't want to be animated before the method call would do that but no matter what I do it always animates all changes.  excludeTarget() doesn't work in this instance either. here's an example of what i'm trying to do:

```
topView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
val transition: Transition = ChangeBounds()
transition.duration = 3000
TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(topView.parent as ViewGroup, transition)
middleView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
```

having a bottom view under the middle one results in it animating the change for both the views.  I guess my question is how to apply some changes to the layout while animating others.  A simple view.animate() would be a huge amount of code because of the complexity of the layout.